# Zabbix and logrt.count doesn't get data

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm running `Debian` and `Zabbix 3.4`.

I've created a custom item with the following syntax:

```
logrt.count["/var/log/^req_log.*.txt$","TIMEOUT"]
```

I'm trying to detect any log file in the format `req_log2018-06-26.txt` with the word `TIMEOUT` and return the number of occurenses.

But no data is gathered with this item, even though there are some files in the directoty which does contain the word.

Is there a way to manually run and test item on server with Zabbix agent running?

Answer (score 2):

From Zabbix version 3.4+, Perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE) are implemented in the Zabbix frontend/backend. Your regexp doesn't look right:

```
$ touch req_log2018-06-26.txt
$ ls -lah | grep -P '^req_log.*.txt$'
<empty result>
$ ls -lah | grep -P 'req_log.*.txt'
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     0 Jul 12 20:37 req_log2018-06-26.txt
```

Try:

```
logrt.count["/var/log/req_log.*.txt","TIMEOUT"]
```